# A problem with mastodon behind nginx

Tags: debian, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've tried to run an instance for myself in mastodon and went through [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-mastodon-social-network-on-debian-12/) and I made a few changes such as, I changed it to single user mode and I did not set up SMTP at all.

Anyway now there is a problem with the server that does not load pictures not in the post of people not mine not even my own avatar. I'm not sure even where to look for logs of this problem. I think it could be due to the wrong nginx config file so I will put it here to start from.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/mastodon`:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream streaming {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000 fail_timeout=0;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=CACHE:10m inactive=7d max_size=1g;

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name mastodon.example.com;
  location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name mastodon.example.com;
   
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/mastodon.access.log;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/mastodon.error.log;

   http2 on; # Enable HTTP/2 - works only on Nginx 1.25.1+

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mastodon.example.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mastodon.example.com/privkey.pem;
   ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mastodon.example.com/chain.pem;
   ssl_session_timeout 1d;

   # Enable TLS versions (TLSv1.3 is required upcoming HTTP/3 QUIC).
   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

   # Enable TLSv1.3's 0-RTT. Use $ssl_early_data when reverse proxying to
   # prevent replay attacks.
   #
   # @see: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_early_data
   ssl_early_data on;

   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384';
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_session_tickets off;
   
   keepalive_timeout    70;
   sendfile             on;
   client_max_body_size 80m;

   # OCSP Stapling ---
   # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
   ssl_stapling on;
   ssl_stapling_verify on;
   ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

   add_header X-Early-Data $tls1_3_early_data;
   
   root /opt/mastodon/web/public;
   
   gzip on;
   gzip_disable "msie6";
   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_comp_level 6;
   gzip_buffers 16 8k;
   gzip_http_version 1.1;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
   
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location ~ ^/(system/accounts/avatars|system/media_attachments/files) {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    root /opt/mastodon/;
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location ~ ^/(emoji|packs) {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location /sw.js {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    proxy_pass_header Server;

    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    proxy_cache CACHE;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 7d;
    proxy_cache_valid 410 24h;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

    tcp_nodelay on;
  }

  location /api/v1/streaming {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Proxy "";

    proxy_pass http://streaming;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    tcp_nodelay on;
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /500.html;
}

# This block is useful for debugging TLS v1.3. Please feel free to remove this
# and use the `$ssl_early_data` variable exposed by NGINX directly should you
# wish to do so.
map $ssl_early_data $tls1_3_early_data {
  "~." $ssl_early_data;
  default "";
}
```

I am not used to docker much but for some reason I couldn't compile some parts for non docker method. Please feel free to ask me for any logs as I'm not sure what you need. I've searched online and couldn't find any help.